check date input for complete date
I have the following code:
<input class="submit-form-on-change" type="month" name="@Model.DatePickerFormKey" value="@Model.InitialValue?.ToString("yyyy-MM")">

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.getElementById('user-filter-content').querySelectorAll('.submit-form-on-change').forEach(function (element) {
            element.addEventListener('change', function () {
                this.form.submit();
            });
        });
    }, false);
</script>

I am able to pick a date via date picker but I would like to be able to also fill the input field using the keyboard.
Now my problem here is that every keystroke triggers the form submit.
Is there any way to check if the value of the input is a full valid date?
So I mean that something like 0202-10 is not possible but 2024-10 or even 1993-10 is.

It’s a bit counterintuitive to auto submit the form if the user happened to type in a valid date.  Maybe they made a mistake on the last character.  Perhaps you need a separate submit button.

check if the value of the input is a full valid date - did you try any of the 2,500+ results for javascript validate date ?

Your HTML here is malformed class="submit-form-on-change type="month" name="

A change event is only dispatched when an input loses focus and the value has changed. Perhaps you're actually using the input event instead?

Ok implemented it like this:
I added a timer/debounce so that even if the date is valid the form will be submitted after a certain time to give the user the possibility to type in the year first and then add a month bigger than 9
<input class="submit-form-on-change-delayed" type="month" name="@Model.DatePickerFormKey" value="@Model.InitialValue?.ToString("yyyy-MM")>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        let debounceTimer;
        const userFilterContent = document.getElementById('user-filter-content');
        const delay = parseInt(userFilterContent.dataset.submitDelay) || 1000; // Default to 1000 ms if no data-delay

        userFilterContent.querySelectorAll('.submit-form-on-change-delayed').forEach(function (element) {
            element.addEventListener('change', function () {
                clearTimeout(debounceTimer);
                debounceTimer = setTimeout(() => {
                    if (isValidDate(this.value)) {
                        this.form.submit();
                    }
                }, delay);
            });
        });
    }, false);

    // Validates that the input string is a valid date formatted as "yyyy-MM"
    function isValidDate(dateString) {

        // Parse the date parts to integers
        const parts = dateString.split("-");
        const year = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
        const month = parseInt(parts[1], 10);

        // Check the ranges of month and year
        if (year < 1000 || year > 9999 || month == 0 || month > 12)
            return false;

        return true;
    };
</script>


When getting data- values you can/should use the dataset property, which was created for that purpose.  Instead of element.getAttribute('data-submit-delay') get the value from the dataset: element.dataset.submitDelay -- when you use getAttribute like that you are doing work that the DOM parsing has already done for you.

consider let or const for these var parts =

The use of parseInt is redundant, the comparisons use type conversion anyway. So let [year, month] = dateString.split("-"). The validation returns true for decimal values like "2024.123-01.876" and for those with more than two parts since it ignores anything after a second "-", such as "2024-11-askdjfaklsdl". There are plenty of questions on how to validate a date.
